# uninitialized local variable used C ++

Tags: c++, char, int

I have rewritten the `char` `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` and `f` as `int` and then assigned them values and I am still getting the error

```
C4700 uninitialized local variable used.
```

How can I fix this? I want the `StudentsGrade = a`; to be returned if the conditions are true.

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    char a; 
    char b; 
    char c; 
    char d; 
    char f; 

    char students;  
    double totalpoints = 0;
    char  StudentsGrade; 


        cout << "Enter Student's name"; 
        cin >> students; 

        if (totalpoints > '360' && totalpoints < '400')
            StudentsGrade = a;
        else if
            (totalpoints > '320' && totalpoints < '359')
            StudentsGrade = b;
        else if
            (totalpoints > '280' && totalpoints < '319')
            StudentsGrade = c;
        else if
            (totalpoints > '240' && totalpoints < '279')
            StudentsGrade = d;
        else
            (totalpoints < '240');
            StudentsGrade = d;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `a`,`b`,... here are variables of type `char`, not the actual characters `'a'`, `'b'`, ....

Comment: Also, I think you need to remove the quotes on the numeric comparisons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see what your problem is. You haven't initialized your char variables.

```
char a = 'a'; 
char b = 'b'; 
char c = 'c';
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code, `a` is a variable, not the actual letter *a*. Try with this:

```
char a = 'a';   // Now the variable a (which is of type char) contains the character a.
```

for all your `char`s, `a` to `f`. This initializes the variables. You could also remove completely the variables, like so:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char students;  
    double totalpoints = 0;
    char  StudentsGrade; 

        cout << "Enter Student's name"; 
        cin >> students; 

        if (totalpoints > 360 && totalpoints < 400)
            StudentsGrade = 'a'; // <-- Notice here!
        else if
            (totalpoints > 320 && totalpoints < 359)
            StudentsGrade = 'b'; // <-- And so on...
        else if
            (totalpoints > 280 && totalpoints < 319)
            StudentsGrade = 'c';
        else if
            (totalpoints > 240 && totalpoints < 279)
            StudentsGrade = 'd';
        else
            (totalpoints < 240);
            StudentsGrade = 'd';

    return 0;
}
```

I think that's what you intended to do in the first place. Finally, notice the numbers (in the conditions) have no more `''` around them.

Comment: thanks I changed the char a = 'a'. It appears to have run because no error codes came up.

Comment: I also noted you use `d` twice, and never `f`. Is this what you really want?

Comment: @StevenM Please consider marking this answer as solved if it answered your question. Otherwise, please clarify your question.

Comment: I fixed the 'd' and marked solved checkbox for these, thanks for the help all

Answer (score 1):

you only need to do the following changes, initialize char variables with actual value like char a = 'a'

```
char a = 'a'; 
char b = 'b'; 
char c = 'c'; 
char d = 'd'; 
char f = 'f';
```

and you also have some more errors, you're using **d** twice.